# Pair production in different reference frames

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, photons, observers, pair-production

I understand that energy of photons is defined by their wavelength/frequency. This frequency (and so energy) will be different for different observers: observer moving towards the photon will see higher frequency than observer moving away from the photon. So basically, the photon might look more energetic from one reference frame and less energetic from some other. It means that photon's energy is based on the observer?

When there are two highly-energetic photons, pair production of electron/positron might take place. How can this actually happen when the energy is based on the observer? It would mean that some observer might see pair production and another one wouldn't see it at all?

Comment: In a frame of reference where one photon has more energy, the other has less; and the particles produced will also have different energies depending on the observer. It all adds up.

Comment: But what about a reference frame, where the photons does not have enough energy to create particles?

Comment: You need conservation of energy and momentum for pair production. This necessitates the photons traveling opposite directions with a sum energy exceeding 1022 keV regardless of any other momentum they may have. And that won't change with reference frame. Can you draw an example where you think the math would fail?

Comment: Ah, okay, i did not realize the photons need to trave opposite directions, i thought they might travel along each other in the same direction.

Comment: There's a bit of confusion here.  You do not need a pair of photons.  A single photon of sufficient energy near a nucleus will do quite nicely. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production

Answer (score 1):

Surprised this hasn't been answered after all these years. Pair production depends on the invariant (rest) mass-energy of the system, not the kinetic energy of a single particle relative to a non-interacting frame. Otherwise we would have a paradox of there being pair production in some reference frames and not others; no - everyone has to agree on whether the pair was created or not, even if we don't all agree of the velocities of the resulting particles.

Once a high energy particle interacts with another, e.g. through a collision or virtual particle exchange, then the relative kinetic energy between them becomes part of the invariant rest mass-energy of the system, and pair production is possible because real energy has been exchanged. Whatever energy is not accounted for by the new particles' rest mass is imparted as kinetic energy, which goes back to being relative rather than invariant.

I'm not sure if I'm alone on this, but personally I like to think of relativistic kinetic energy as more of a potential energy rather than something intrinsic. Something zipping through space all by its lonesome self at a constant velocity does nothing interesting - and certainly doesn't produce new particles - until it interacts with something else. Before that the energy is just hypothetical.